# Angular project has 2 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: angular, npm-audit

The question I have is whether this warning is unique to me or if I can ignore this error.

**ng version**

[image]

When I create a project using the command **ng new projectName**, and then check the package integrity using **npm audit** this is the result I get
[image]

The **npm audit fix --force** command does not resolve the issue. It only generates more warnings.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

update your `@angular-devkit/...` from `15.2.2` to `15.2.4` in your package.json and run `npm i`